# How to invert all view's colors below a UIView or layer?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uiview, calayer

I'm trying to accomplish inverting colors to negative under a layer/view.

Is there a way to implement a layer that **affects everything in the screen under itself**, not just subviews. Or is there a way to invert colors in a specific region on the whole screen?

For example, I aim to add a view/layer on top of the selected row (white one) and invert colors every other view under the newly added view/layer. This means now row text should be black, not white and also the red view should be inverted.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It's possible you could grab the rect as an image and apply a `CIColorInvert CIFilter`, but that would likely not be a good solution. Are your "rows" going to be particularly complex? Perhaps with images that you want "converted to negative"? If not, it would almost certainly be a much route to just change the colors via code.

Comment: @DonMag thanks for your answer. But I want to invert whatever is in the middle of the screen. For example, the red gradient layer should be inverted and also the selected row's title text color should be reverted white to black. (Actually I want it white but in this case it's already white so it'd be inverted to black) So I can't grab and apply invert to one of these views.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult feat, since capturing everything in a specified region would likely require clipping some views. This can't be done programmatically ( yet ) and requires visual manipulation.

The basic idea is to get an image of a certain part of the screen, perform your changes, and apply the image as a non-interactive overlay in the exact same spot.

This is much easier said than done, and even with new tools like SwiftUI's [ImageRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer) introduced in iOS 16, the performance and reliability of updating the snapshot real-time is nowhere near production ready.

My preferred solution ( if you're okay with leveraging a private API ) is to bring in the CABackdropLayer class from Objective-C, and apply your affects to the layer. There's a good chance that Apple uses the same API for their real-time blur effects.

This will get things working in SwiftUI:

```
//
//  APIName: Backdrop
//  Developed by _
//

//  MARK: - Imports

import SwiftUI

//
//

//  MARK: - Classes

/// Creates a `UIView` from a `CABackdropLayer`.
///
/// - Warning: Uses a private API.
///
@available ( iOS 16.0, * )
final public class UIBackdrop: UIView {
    
    /// The selector to call from Objective-C.
    ///
    private static let selector: String = { [ "Layer", "Backdrop", "CA" ] .reversed ( ) .joined ( ) } ( )
    
    /// Gets the `CABackdropLayer` class.
    ///
    override public class var layerClass: AnyClass { NSClassFromString ( self. selector ) ?? CALayer.self }
    
}

//
//

//  MARK: - Structures

/// A `CABackdropLayer` wrapper that captures the content behind it.
///
/// - Warning: Uses a private API.
///
@available ( iOS 16.0, * )
public struct Backdrop: UIViewRepresentable {

    /// Creates the UI view.
    ///
    public func makeUIView ( context: Context ) -> UIBackdrop { UIBackdrop ( ) }

    /// Updates the UI view.
    ///
    public func updateUIView ( _ uiView: UIBackdrop, context: Context ) { }
    
}

//
//
```

I haven't had any issues with app review so you should be fine in that regard, but use at your own risk.